# How to get proper tags(<>) instead of &lt; &gt; in postman response(application/xml)

Tags: xml, spring-boot, xslt, redis, postman

Not getting proper xml tags in postman response body.
Saving content in string format in Redis cache, then extracting the data from redis cache and sending response to GET api call in the postman.

Current Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <Status>COMPLETED</Status>
    <Output>
        <Extracted>
            <Document>
                <Id>067272b3-856c-4bca-895b-1695a242ddc9</Id>
                <Name>barcode</Name>
                <Content>&lt;page&gt;
   &lt;block blockType="Barcode"&gt;
      &lt;text&gt;
         &lt;paragraph&gt;
            &lt;line&gt;08675309&lt;/line&gt;
         &lt;/paragraph&gt;
      &lt;/text&gt;
   &lt;/block&gt;
&lt;/page&gt;
              </Content>
    </Document>
</Extracted>
</Output>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
        <Status>COMPLETED</Status>
        <Output>
        <Extracted>
                <Document>
                        <Id>123</Id>
                        <Name>barcode</Name>
                        <Content>
                                     <page>
                                          <block blockType="Barcode">
                                             <text>
                                                <paragraph>
                                                   <line>08675309</line>
                                                </paragraph>
                                             </text>
                                          </block>
                                       </page>
                                       <page>
                                            <block blockType="Barcode">
                                               <text>
                                                  <paragraph>
                                                     <line>08675899</line>
                                                  </paragraph>
                                               </text>
                                            </block>
                                        </page>
                        </Content>
                </Document>
</Extracted>
</Output>
</root>
```

Comment: No sure if I'm following everything, but it looks like you're saving the content as a string, not appending XML nodes to the content.  Setting a element's content to a string will escape <> to &lt; &gt; etc.

Comment: Yes @WilliamWalseth you are correct, I 'm saving the content as a string.
Can you please guide me how can I save it as a XML node?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't work with Redis or Spring-boot, just XML and DOM programming,